# Cannot solve compiler errors while extracting reqwest::Response from a reqwest::Client request

Tags: rust, actix-web, reqwest

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to error handle this piece of code.

This is the endpoint of my actix_web api, up until now everything works:

```
pub async fn simple_moving_average() -> HttpResponse {  
      if Client::new()
        .get("https://coinranking1.p.rapidapi.com/coins")
        .header(
        "X-RapidAPI-Key",
        "MY_KEY")
        .send()
        .await
        .is_err()
    {
        HttpResponse::BadRequest().finish();
    }
    HttpResponse::Ok().finish()
}
```

It's when I try to extract the data from the response that the compiler starts screaming at me:

```
[...]
let response = Client::new()
        .get("https://coinranking1.p.rapidapi.com/coins")
        .header(
        "X-RapidAPI-Key",
        "MY_KEY")
        .send()
        .await?
        .json::<Root>()
        .await?;
HttpResponse::Ok().finish()
}
```

cargo check ->

> he `?` operator can only be used in an async function that returns
> `Result` or `Option` (or another type that implements `FromResidual`)
> the trait `FromResidual<Result<Infallible, reqwest::Error>>` is not
> implemented for `HttpResponse`rustcE0277 simple_moving_average.rs(50,
> 65): this function should return `Result` or `Option` to accept `?`

`Root` in `.json::<Root>()` is just a struct representing json payload. I generated it from this [website](https://transform.tools/json-to-rust-serde), not sure if it's relevant

how do I solve that? My final goal here would be to return a json response containing the data I get from this request. I've tried implementing the ::thiserror crate but I cannot figure out how it works and honestly I would prefer to understand how error handling works before using some fast solution.

I've tried following what compiler suggests but I cannot seem to solve the situation.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to include the answer. Instead you can [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I solved by using the dyn trait

correct code:

```
pub async fn simple_moving_average() -> 
Result<HttpResponse, Box<dyn std::error::Error>>{ [...] }
```